# Changing the google chart API title and axis position and font style setting?

Tags: google-visualization

I am working on using the google chart api to create a scatter chart, but it seems that the position of title can only be changed to 'in' or 'out', and align to the left side. How can I change it to be centered outside of the chart? Also, how to cancel the style italic for the axis label? Thanks for your help!!

Comment: It's not perfect, but for the italic axis label try setting as follows: titleTextStyle: { fontSize: 14, bold:true }

Comment: For column chart, you can refer here.. https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#Data_Format

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For canceling the italic style on the axis titles, do something like this:

```
vAxis: {title: "Hours", titleTextStyle: {italic: false}},
hAxis: {title: "Month", titleTextStyle: {italic: false}},
```

It is an undocumented feature, but it works most of the time.